# Multiple markers with text on Android Google Maps API v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

My goal is to have multiple markers with text on each on the Android Google Maps API **v2** map. The info windows approach (showInfoWindow()) is not suitable, because only one info window is displayed at a time. For example I want to have something like this: [image]

As you can see each marker has its own data (number for this example) displayed all the time.
How can I achieve this with Android Google Maps API **v2**?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

to do that you'll have to customize the icon of each individual marker to be what you need.
Here's the link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#customize_a_marker

Then you can put some PNG resources (a blue, a yellow and a red), and at runtime get correct Bitmap, write the text on the bitmap by code, and then set as the custom-marker with the `fromBitmap (Bitmap image)` method.

Answer (score 3):

try out this

```
LinearLayout tv = (LinearLayout) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.marker_dialog, null, false);

tv.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
tv.layout(0, 0, tv.getMeasuredWidth(), tv.getMeasuredHeight());

tv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
tv.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bm = tv.getDrawingCache();

LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitudemy, longitudemy);


BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bm);
BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitudemy, longitudemy)).title("origin").snippet("Srivastava").icon(icon));
// Showing the current location in Google Map
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("destination").snippet("Srivastava").icon(icon));
```

Comment: Define your custum layout xml of imageview and text view xml

Answer (score 0):

As an **update**:
android maps utils now has a Marker Clustering Utility
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils