# How to show a label(String) over a marker in google maps static api?

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a vehicle routing algorithm I need to show vehicles on maps with there driver name on top of the label. I have done the marker part it looks like this.
[image]

However I would like to display driver's name on top of every marker. Can you suggest me any way to do it?

My google maps static api url looks like this

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=26.900,75.800&zoom=11&size=400x400&markers=color:blue|label:Driver|&markers=color:green|label:Req|26.925571778374632,75.81166033197894|&markers=color:blue|label:others|26.944421737574313,75.8072312248272|26.941722318252367,75.82851178160593|26.909618922760885,75.85079885210592|26.92537722447672,75.85626510000787|26.969253598622025,75.81687986464266|26.933707124740607,75.84999920863306|26.986333832648626,75.88755301718626|26.945330532812793,75.81567681826434|26.942938812152843,75.81989078933901|&markers=color:red|label:Req|26.8983489,75.796436|
```

Ps: I am using java.

Comment: Hope it'll be help you:-

 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17837510/map-markers-with-text-in-google-maps-android-api-v2
 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303667/multiple-markers-with-text-on-android-google-maps-api-v2
 3. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579426/google-android-maps-api-v2-show-marker-tittle-always

Answer (score 1):

I think the best you can do with the Static Maps API v2 is to have different initials and colors for different markers. Like [this example](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn%20Bridge,New%20York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap%20&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318%20&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284).

You may be able to do something with the [custom icons](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/overview#CustomIcons) too, but it does not seem to be working as far as I can tell.

The best practice here is to implement it using the [JavaScript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Is this possible with the version you're using?

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Sydney")
            .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.")
            .position(sydney));
}
```

Here is the code in action: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/